# Docker and Kubernetes integrations compatibility matrix?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, integration

Two example integrations of Docker and Kubernetes are OpenShift and Rancher Labs AFAIK.

Sadly but in fact we have not completely escaped us from the dependency hell.

**Question: is there an established source of information which distributions here package which versions (like Ubutu/Debian version chronicles on Wikipedia)?**

*Background.*

Not-so-obvious facts for newbies (judged by my learnings so far) are (defining acceptable technical usability to a level that you do no need hours to debug even 101 tutorials):

- Kubernetes is very dynamic project and it is not so easy to deploy it as-is (but seem to get better with each version, also thanks to kubeadm I would say)
- Kubernetes does not support any Docker versions coming after the community fork to moby and Docker CE.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657320/which-docker-versions-will-k8s-1-7-support

Comment: I don't exactly get your second bullet... (moby use containerd as does docker engine enterprise or community edition and I don't see the relation with k8s here). In fact I don't get the overall question, k8s is an orchestrator, it can use docker or rkt as container engine.

Comment: k8s tutorials draw however that Docker daemon has to be there, I think in most cases it is the setup? or is this obsolete information then.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657320/which-docker-versions-will-k8s-1-7-support ; k8s 1.8 is not there yet but again which compatibility is there then

Comment: Yes,  docker engine or rkt, docker one is more stable I think but that's a version of docker which is supported, I don't get what you're after with your fork mention

Comment: Docker engine v. 1.12 and 1.13. were the versions before the fork to 17.x-ce which  actually could have been 1.17, right? https://github.com/moby/moby/releases?after=v17.04.0-ce-rc1

Comment: Yep, docker has changed its versioning system, moby follow it as highlighted in this tag: https://github.com/moby/moby/releases/tag/v17.03.0-ce-rc1 (I still see no fork, just a version scheme change)

Comment: oh I see now; so there is after all just one code base be it ce (=moby) or ee (=Docker Inc.?) - and back to the question, no compatibility matrix for integrations of different versions of Docker Engine with different ... other important and popular constructs around there using it ;)

Comment: Would you mind joining https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54506/chatops to discuss it further ? I've the feeling there's something to clear up again (moby != docker ce, they are different products, so there's still something unclear there). concerning k8s: from [the doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/#learning): "The minimum required Docker version will vary as the kubelet version changes. The newest stable release is a good choice." and "rkt is an alternative to Docker. You only need to install one of Docker or rkt. The minimum version required is v0.5.6."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Kubernetes release has an **External Dependencies** section in the respective Changelog. E.g.:

[CHANGELOG-1.14](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.14.md#external-dependencies):

> The list of validated docker versions has changed. 1.11.1 and 1.12.1
>   have been removed. The current list is 1.13.1, 17.03, 17.06, 17.09,
>   18.06, 18.09.

[CHANGELOG-1.13](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.13.md#external-dependencies):

> The list of validated docker versions remain unchanged at 1.11.1,
>   1.12.1, 1.13.1, 17.03, 17.06, 17.09, 18.06 since Kubernetes 1.12.

[CHANGELOG-1.12](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.12.md#external-dependencies):

> The list of validated docker versions was updated to 1.11.1, 1.12.1,
>   1.13.1, 17.03, 17.06, 17.09, 18.06.

*and so on...*